# "Closure (deleted)" in profile's Votes Cast is inaccurate if the the close vote was cast after the deleted question was later undeleted and reopened

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I voted to close a question on March 31st, 2013.

This question had previously been deleted on March 15th, 2012 then undeleted on March 16th 2012.

In the "Votes Cast" tab of my profile, the closure vote is annotated with "(deleted)", even though the question is not currently deleted, and the undeletion happened long before my close vote.

> [image]

The "(deleted)" annotation should only be displayed if the post was deleted *after* the close vote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "(deleted)" does **not** mean the post was deleted.

It means that the closevote expired, therefore the *closevote* was deleted, not the post.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I initially considered that, but decided it couldn't be the case because the "(deleted)" annotation is displayed beside my vote to close on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412183/how-can-i-have-a-black-background-for-my-whole-site-using-css) and that vote successfully closed the question -- it was not deleted, or at least not in any meaningful way. I guess that's a different bug.

Comment: If the deleted is really meant to mean the vote expired, it should really say expired instead. Saying deleted is just confusing.

Comment: I have a lot of Closure(deleted) where the post is actually closed and my userid appears on the list of people who voted to close it - so that means my closevote didn't expire right? - is this a bug?