# On the votes tab in the profile show successful closed votes as "successful" not "deleted"

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, voting, profile-page

### Background

Within the voting tab of my profile any questions that I have voted to close which have then actually been closed are shown as deleted.

[image]

The related [bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175610/what-causes-close-votes-to-be-annotated-with-deleted)  has been marked [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) I shall argue that it should be changed;

### Proposal

I propose that any close vote that ultimately leads to a closure be marked "successful" rather than "deleted" as whatever the internal processes the end user will see it that way

### Reasoning

From a users perspective their vote has not been deleted; it is still shown under the closed question as "closed by Voter1, Voter2 ...." as such the vote is "successful" not "deleted", from a users point of view a deleted vote would be one that aged away or was invalidated in some other way.

Comment: Even after I read [that question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175610/187824) many times whenever I see "deleted" under the vote, the first thought come in my mind is either my vote is removed or the question is deleted. It really needs to be changed.

Comment: I agree that deleted is too vague. On the other hand, each question closed and not fixed is not really a success ;)

Answer (score 4):

I propose that the text displays the actual closure reason instead of simply saying "successful".

Thus there would be seven possible states:

1. Active (if the vote is currently active)
2. Expired (if the vote has aged away)
3. Duplicate
4. Off-Topic
5. Unclear
6. Too Broad
7. Opinion Based

That way a user could review his or her close votes and see for what reason the question was closed actually.

Comment: Even better, the reason I propose just "successful" is because internally this is deleted so it would be a simple `if (deleted){"successful"}` but if this was easily implementable I'd favour this

Comment: Also "Active" if the vote is currently active and  "Expired" if the vote is expired after 4 days.

Comment: @hims056: Good suggestion. I edited my answer accordingly.